# How to avoid conflicting bash binary during Cygwin install on Windows with Linux Subsystem?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cygwin

I'm writing an installer script using Inno Setup that will install Cygwin via its command line setup.  However, when doing a command line installation of Cygwin on a machine that already has bash in its environment path, I get this output in Cygwin's setup log:

```
Adding required dependency bash: Selecting already-installed version .
```

I'm testing this installation on the free Windows Enterprise OS that ships with Parallels.  This comes with the Windows Linux Subsystem (WSL) already activated and has an installation of an Ubuntu distro.

For the Cygwin installation, I've downloaded all the packages I need for the app locally and the Cygwin setup, and all the packages install successfully, but there are some errors in the post-installation because I think it's trying to create profiles, etc. within bash, but it cannot find it — probably because it skipped installing the bash binary in the local packages directory since it already found one:

```
running: c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/000-
cygwin-post-install.sh"
abnormal exit: exit code=-6
running: c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile 
"/etc/postinstall/coreutils.sh"
abnormal exit: exit code=-6
running: c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/base-files-mketc.sh"
abnormal exit: exit code=-6
running: c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/base-
files-profile.sh"
abnormal exit: exit code=-6
running: c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/ca-certificates.sh"
abnormal exit: exit code=-6
running: c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/man-db.sh"
abnormal exit: exit code=-6
running: c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile 
"/etc/postinstall/mintty.sh"
abnormal exit: exit code=-6
running: c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/zp_man-db.sh"
abnormal exit: exit code=-6
Ending cygwin install
```

To be sure, I'm running Windows 10 (Version 1709, Build 16299.214) and bash.exe is found here by default `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`

Is there a way to force the Cygwin installer to avoid skipping the bash installation?  I looked at the switches / flags in Cygwin's setup help, but don't see any that would do this.  How can I be sure Cygwin installs bash.exe in its `/bin` directory even if a machine already has WSL installed and activated?

Comment: `running: c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe` indicates the right bash was used. The problem is NOT on the WSL.

Comment: @matzeri I don't understand your comment.  In my case, there is no such file at C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe because it never installed as I noted above.  That's why the errors are ocurring.  The error is definitely a result of bash.exe already being present in the C:\Windows\System32 folder which is already in the environment path.

Comment: The problem had to do with the fact that there was a setup.ini file that apparently had Cygwin's installer always use the "already installed version".  I had to remove the setup.ini file, and now bash is installed!